# Extracting Multiple Similar Rows For Each Distinct Type Of A Column

Tags: mysql, sql

Input

```
+--------+------+------+
|  col1  | col2 | col3 |
+--------+------+------+
| apple  | d    |   10 |
| apple  | d    |   44 |
| apple  | e    |   55 |
| orange | d    |   99 |
| orange | c    |   33 |
| orange | d    |   10 |
| banana | e    |   55 |
| banana | d    |   10 |
+--------+------+------+
```

Required Output

```
+--------+------+------+
|  col1  | col2 | col3 |
+--------+------+------+
| apple  | d    |   10 |
| orange | d    |   10 |
| banana | d    |   10 |
+--------+------+------+
```

We will be checking col2 and col3 for N different type of fruits.

We want to list only those those where col2 and col3 values are same and the row is present for all fruits

## Extended explanation:

You can think of it like this:-

**STEP 1**

Separate out all the different type of fruits:-

Apple:-

```
+-------+------+------+
| col1  | col2 | col3 |
+-------+------+------+
| apple | d    |   10 |
| apple | d    |   44 |
| apple | e    |   55 |
+-------+------+------+
```

Orange:-

```
+--------+------+------+
|  col1  | col2 | col3 |
+--------+------+------+
| orange | d    |   99 |
| orange | c    |   33 |
| orange | d    |   10 |
+--------+------+------+
```

Banana:-

```
+--------+------+------+
|  col1  | col2 | col3 |
+--------+------+------+
| banana | e    |   55 |
| banana | d    |   10 |
+--------+------+------+
```

**STEP 2:-**

Now choose only those rows who

- have SAME col2 & col3 values

AND

- It is present in all types of fruits.

**OBSERVATION:-**

'apple e 55' and 'banana e 55' have same col2 and col3 values but it is not selected because 'orange e 55' is not present.

If you are using temporary tables then please make sure that it should be generic. It should support N number of fruits.

Note:- This is not an assignment of a student `:D` . I'm explaining it in simple words because it is a part of a long and lengthy query and I've ZERO idea of how to tackle it. I've been using a technique of creating temporary tables, but I was facing some problems. It was not made generic. So, I believe there might be some better solution of this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you can get the record that is present in all fruits regardless of `name` via this query,

```
SELECT  col2, col3
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY col2, col3
HAVING  COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1) FROM tableName)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0472b/2)

The total number of record in a group of two columns: `col2` and `col3` must be equal to the total number of fruits. `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1) FROM tableName`.

So to get all the records that has a combination present in all fruits, we need to `JOIN` it with the table itself.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  col2, col3
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY col2, col3
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1) FROM tableName)
        ) b ON a.col2 = b.col2 AND
                a.col3 = b.col3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0472b/1)

Comment: @Omar Tariq You may want to add an PRIMARY KEY(col2, col3, col1) that way you remove the need off "Using temporary; Using filesort" what will slow down on large tables  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1901d/1

Comment: Will this query run okay if there are more columns in the table. But they are not involved with col1, col2, and col3 in anyway?

Comment: yes it will work - `Will this query run okay if there are more columns in the table. But they are not involved with col1, col2, and col3 in anyway?`

Comment: **SECOND PART OF THIS QUESTION** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774518/two-same-type-of-queries-on-same-type-tables-but-different-output