# Two Same Type Of Queries On Same Type Tables But Different Output

Tags: mysql, sql

In context to my previous question I asked few hours ago:-

[Extracting Multiple Similar Rows For Each Distinct Type Of A Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772714/extracting-multiple-similar-rows-for-each-distinct-type-of-a-column)

Some helpful guys gave me a smart solution of my problem. I mapped the solution on my database table which is almost same as the dummy table I designed for the question. But unfortunately the query is giving wrong output on my original table. I believe that its a quick fix and I'm unable to spot it.

Solution given to me by some helpful SO users:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0472b/1

After I've mapped the solution:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/082d9/1

The correct output for my table would be:-

```
+---+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----+
| d | Johnny Bravo | August, 27 2013 00:00:00+0000 |     NAB      | Same Amount | 150 |
+---+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----+
| d | Courage Dog  | August, 27 2013 00:00:00+0000 | Commonwealth | Same Amount | 150 |
+---+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----+
```

This question is more like a spot-the-difference images `:D`

Comment: i wrote an article on dba stackexchange why you should always use an PRIMARY KEY/UNIQUE key in an table when you use the InnoDB engine http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by/48184#48184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the original solution, I was thinking "what if there are duplicates in columns 2 and 3".  Lo and behold, that is the problem.  Here is the revised query that works on your SQL Fiddle:

```
SELECT ht.*
FROM helper_table ht INNER JOIN
     (SELECT `date`, `amount`
      FROM helper_table ht
      GROUP BY `date`, `amount`
      HAVING  COUNT(distinct `name`) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `name`) FROM helper_table)
     ) da
     ON ht.`date` = da.`date` AND
        ht.`amount` = da.`amount`;
```

This still assumes that the fields `date` and `amount` don't contain `NULL` values (or, at least, NULL values don't match).

Comment: Bingo! Quick and accurate answer, well appreciated.

Comment: @Omar Tariq i think i have an Déjà vu... but an KEY on (date, amount) would remove the need that MySQL needs an filesort on HAVING  COUNT(distinct `name`)